# Google Analytics to sort by amount of traffic in the last 24 hours only

Tags: views, google-analytics

I am using [Google Analytics Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter) at the moment to sort the content by traffic (in Views). However, at the moment Google Analytics Counter only supports `Pageview Total` which is the total views (all time). What I am looking for is to sort the content by `amount of traffic in the last 24 hours` only.

Created an issue in the project page as well: https://www.drupal.org/node/2507213

I am also reading the Google Analytics doc now (first acquaintance). Thinking that I might need to do some settings on Google Analytics panel in order to achieved what I want.